# Google script reading xml

Tags: xml

I've xml file like this:

```
<rowset name="skills" key="typeID" columns="typeID,skillpoints,level,published">
<row typeID="2495" skillpoints="32000" level="3" published="1"/>
<row typeID="2505" skillpoints="63568" level="3" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3184" skillpoints="25562" level="2" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3300" skillpoints="45255" level="4" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3301" skillpoints="8000" level="3" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3310" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3311" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3312" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3315" skillpoints="1000" level="1" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3316" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3317" skillpoints="1250" level="1" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3318" skillpoints="2829" level="2" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3319" skillpoints="250" level="1" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3327" skillpoints="8000" level="3" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3328" skillpoints="16000" level="3" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3330" skillpoints="500" level="1" published="1"/>
<row typeID="3340" skillpoints="1000" level="1" published="1"/>
```

And i'm trying to create function to read level value when i give there typeID value. I've been trying to do it in many ways, but i failed. The best i got is finding right typeID, but then it shows me a message, that "You can't call „getName” method of null class"

```
function skillLvl(id) {
  id=3389;
  var url = "{not important}";
  var document = readXml(url);
  var end = document.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChild("row");
  var v1 = end.getAttribute("typeID").toString();
  var v2 = end.getAttribute("level").toString();
  var lvl = 0;
  if (v1 = "4"){
    lvl = v2;
  }

  return lvl;

}
```

there is also this before:

```
<rowset name="jumpClones" key="jumpCloneID" columns="jumpCloneID,typeID,locationID,cloneName">
<row jumpCloneID="23230289" typeID="164" locationID="60003466" cloneName=""/>
<row jumpCloneID="23205549" typeID="164" locationID="60009439" cloneName=""/>
</rowset>
```

UPDATE:

It's returning "" when calling skillLvl(2495),this is full code:

```
function skillLvl(id) {
  //id=3389;
  var idd="skills";
  var url = "(...)";
  var document = readXml(url);
 var rowsets = document.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChildren("rowset");
  var level=null;
for (var i=0;level==null && i<rowsets.length;i++)
{
    var rowset=rowsets[i];
    level=getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id);
}
// In this line, if level!=null, it is found.
}
function getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id)
{
    var rows = rowset.getChildren("row");
    var level=null;
    for (var i=0;level==null && i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var row=rows[i];
        if (row.getAttribute("typeID")==id)
        {
            level=row.getAttribute("level");
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

it may be something wrong with this one:

```
function readXml(url) {
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  return XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `getChildren` method to get all the `row` nodes, and then iterate them to get the desired id:

```
  var rows = document.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChildren("row");
  var level=null;
  for (var i=0;level==null && i<rows.length;i++)
  {
      var row=rows[i];
      var typeIdAttr=row.getAttribute("typeID");
      if (typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==id)
      {
          level=row.getAttribute("level");
      }
  }
```

**Update**

If there are more than one `rowset`, you'd better split the searching logic between two functions:

```
// Main function:
var rowsets = document.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChildren("rowset");
for (var i=0;level==null && i<rowsets.length;i++)
{
    var rowset=rowsets[i];
    level=getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id);
}
// In this line, if level!=null, it is found.

function getLevelByTypeFromRowset(rowset, id)
{
    var rows = rowset.getChildren("row");
    var level=null;
    for (var i=0;level==null && i<rows.length;i++)
    {
        var row=rows[i];
        var typeIdAttr=row.getAttribute("typeID");
        if (typeIdAttr && typeIdAttr.getValue()==id)
        {
            level=row.getAttribute("level").getValue();
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

(It would be better if you could use *xpath expressions* to simplify this logic, but I haven't found how to in Google Script).

Comment: ya, but i've forgot, that this is not only <rowset> tag : `<rowset name="jumpClones" key="jumpCloneID" columns="jumpCloneID,typeID,locationID,cloneName">
<row jumpCloneID="23230289" typeID="164" locationID="60003466" cloneName=""/>
<row jumpCloneID="23205549" typeID="164" locationID="60009439" cloneName=""/>
</rowset>`(it's in first post)

Comment: Ok, also check my update,(i'm completly new to js...)

Comment: Method `skillLvl` misses a `return level;` at the end.

Comment: @10anat120 Be clearer, please. What does "Still nothing" mean? What is the result? Have you debugged your program? What is it expected to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: It suppose to give me `level` value for given `typeID` into google docs, and it's returning empty cell. However if i'd change `var level=null;` to `var level=0;` in `skillLvl(id)` it's returning me 0, which if i'm right means that `for` isn't working

Comment: OK. My mistake. Look at my edit: An intermediate variable `typeIdAttr` is needed here.

Comment: Still nothing, even when i put `level = i;` into `for` in `skillLvl(id)`. Is there any way to download source to string, that i could just split it?

Comment: My mistake again. Sorry! There was an `if` too much. I've updated it.

Comment: Still there was a missing `.getValue()` at the end of `level=getAttribute(...)`.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm sorry for all these come-and-go's... :-(

Comment: You have nothing to sorry about, i'd need a month to do it on my own :)